# Properties of the interior of a set

Tags: general-topology

Consider $ \tau_1 , \tau_2$ two topologies defined on X.
I want to prove that these are equivalent:

(i) $
 \tau_2 \subseteq \tau_1
$

(ii) $A\in X$, $(A^2)^\circ \subseteq (A^1)^\circ $

I have started by proving  that (i) implies (ii) by definition but I don't know if this is correct.

$x\in (A^2)^\circ$ if and only if $(A^2)\in N_x^2$ but since $ \tau_2 \subseteq \tau_1$ then $(A^2)\in N_x^2$ and this implies  $x\in (A^1)^\circ$??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with $(i) \to (ii)$. For a fixed $A$, we need to show that $A^{2\circ} \subset A^{1 \circ}$. Let us take any $x \in A^{2\circ}$. By the definition, $x \in N$, where $N \in \tau_2$ and $x \in N \subset A$. But since $\tau_2 \subset \tau_1$, we also have $N \in \tau_2$, and (because the other condition $x \in N \subset A$ does not depend on the topology) we have by definition $x \in A^{1\circ}$.

Next, we do $(ii) \to (i)$. Let $A \in \tau_2$; we need to show that $A \in \tau_1$. By the definition, we have $A = A^{2 \circ} $. By $(ii)$ we have $A^{2\circ} \subset A^{1 \circ}$. By the definition of interior, we have $A^{1\circ} \subset A$. Hence, $A = A^{2 \circ}  \subset A^{1 \circ}\subset A$. This is only possible when all the inclusions in the chain are in fact equalities; in particular $ A^{1 \circ} = A$, and this  $A \in \tau_1$.

Comment: I got confused with the indices of A when you proof the first implication. Why do you just write A instead of $A_1$ or $A_2$ in each case?

Comment: Actually, I am confused by the notation you used. Surely $(A^{1})^\circ$ is supposed to be the interior of the set $A$ in topology $\tau_1$, is that right? So, is $A^1$ the set $A$, viewed in topology $\tau_1$, and likewise for $A^2$? If so, then I don't make this distinction: a set is just a set, with no topology included. The equality is the equality of sets, nothing more